# PUT request is Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Rest Api in angular and my GET request is working properly but when i edit the data and do some changes , my PUT request is not working and data is not getting saved into json file.

Here is my code :

```
<div ng-show="contact" id="contacts_edit"> 
<button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="toggle_edit()"> Edit </button>`

<button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="toggle_save()"> Save </button> 

<b> Street:</b> 
<p ng-hide="editMode"> 
   {{cts.selectedcontact.location.street}} 
</p>
<input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="cts.selectedcontact.location.street">
```

Angular code :

```
$scope.toggle_save = function(contacts){
    $http.put('http://localhost:3000/contacts' + contacts.id)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response)
            $scope.cts.selectedcontact = response.data.contacts;
        })
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: contacts is undefined @MikaelLennholm

Comment: **contacts** is the name of the json-data

Comment: @kishore you are not passing the **contacts** parameter to the toggle_save()

Comment: A `$http.put` request requires both a `url` and a `data` argument. The code is only supplying a `url`.

Comment: So then your issue isn't with the PUT request but the fact that you invoke `$scope.toggle_save` with no argument, or an argument that's `undefined`

Comment: I tried that also. But it showed the same error @RNS

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: @kishore your not passing contacts parameter when you click on save button i.e. ng-click="toggle_save()" but your function is expecting a parameter to be passed $scope.toggle_save = function(contacts)

Comment: I am getting the request from the server. After that , when i click on the toggle_edit , the data content should get edited and when i click on the toggle_save, the edited contents should get saved and it should be updated in my json data file. For saving the updated content , I am using PUT request @georgeawg

Comment: The PUT request is malformed. The code is missing the `data` argument.

Comment: `ng-click="toggle_save()"`. You're not invoking the `$scope.toggle_save` function with any argument, so of course the expected first argument `contacts` is `undefined` inside the function

Comment: If i don't invoke my ' toggle_save() ' . How would I save and pass the content to the url @MikaelLennholm

Comment: You need to invoke it of course, but you need to invoke it **with the data you want to save**

Comment: You should invoke your function with passing an *contacts* argument take a look at your code *ng-click="toggle_save()"* you are not passing anything

Comment: Would you mind . Can u create a small plnkr. So that I will come to know @MikaelLennholm

Answer (score 0):

```
put(url, data, [config]);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put

What you currently have is a simple URL, which doesn't even have any parameters as you append an id at the end of the URL.

```
$scope.toggle_save = function(contacts){
    $http.put('http://localhost:3000/contacts', contacts.id)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response)
            $scope.cts.selectedcontact = response.data.contacts;
        })
}
```

Would be the more correct way of passing an id to /contacts route.

Putting that aside, you are not passing any data into your function.

```
ng-click="toggle_save()"
```

Has an empty constructor, so not sure where you're getting contracts from. You might want to pass a model in, unless you have a variable called 'contacts' defined in your controller which I doubt seeing your model bindings.
Therefore passing `cts.selectedcontact` object inside your `ng-click="toggle_save(cts.selectedcontact)"` would make it most likely work assuming that this object contains the properties you're trying to access.

Another assumption is that `cts` is your controller alias and selectedcontact is an object attached to `$scope`, i.e. `$scope.selectedcontact = {};`